# JSONCompareResult does not work with GSON for primitive type integers. Why?

Tags: java, json, gson, assert, jsonassert

I was playing around with the [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) and [JSONAssert](https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert) libraries when I ran into this problem.

I have the following function to compare two integers:

```
    private static void runCompareInts(int source, int target){

        JSONCompareResult result = JSONCompare.compareJSON(new Gson().toJson(source),
            new Gson().toJson(target),
            JSONCompareMode.NON_EXTENSIBLE);

        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(result.getFieldFailures())) {
            System.out.println("Objects are same.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Objects are not the same. Difference: " + result);
        }

    }
```

When I run `runCompareInts(1, 2)`, I get `"Objects are same."` as the result, which should not be the case.

I found that `new Gson().toJson(1)` returns the String `"1"`, which is a valid JSON string and hence the comparison should proceed correctly and go into the `else` block.

Comparing the integers using `JSONAssert.assertNotEquals("1", "2", true)` does not result in any exception. This implies that the Gson converted values are not the problem.

Can anyone tell me what the error with my `runCompareInts()` function is? Thank you.

EDIT: `JSONAssert.assertNotEquals(new Gson().toJson(source), new Gson().toJson(target), true)` also works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use `result.isFailureOnField()` inside if block.

I see an issue with messages in jsonassert library, method `compareJson(final JSONString expected, final JSONString actual)` of `JSONCompare` class is returning empty error message on failure.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried doing that but when I print out the value of `result.isFailureOnField()` it gives me `false`.

Comment: Thats the expected behavior, method 'isFailureOnField()' returns boolean so it will be either true or false. And I stated earlier that there is an issue with library it doesn't log differences in fail() method for primitive type is you won't get messages. Although as both fields are known, you can write custom method by your own.